# select an input by name with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select this input with jquery without assigning an id or class?

```
<input type="hidden" name="nOfAnswers[]" value="2">
```

At the moment I use:

```
    $nOfAnswers = $table.find("input[name*='nOfAnswers[]']");
```

But when I print it:

```
    console.log($nOfAnswers.html());
```

It prints a blank line to the console.

Comment: Your code is working as expected.  What do you expect `$nOfAnswers.html()` to print?  (PS. `.html()` is using `.innerHTML` internally.)  Try to `console.log($nOfAnswers.length);` to see if the selector is even working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be: `$nOfAnswers.val()`

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can try

```
$nOfAnswers = $("input[name='nOfAnswers'").val()
```